# RxJava Spring Boot microservice AsyncReturnValueHandler gives 404 No message available ERROR

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rx-java

I have written a Spring Boot micro service using RxJava and you may find the [project](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/SpringBootRxJava) here. Everything works fine perfectly. Now currently I am transforming RxJava `Observable`s into `DeferredResult` inside my Controller/Resource classes. I have heard that this can be done using a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` and a simple adapter of `Observable` to `DeferredResult`. I started implementing this. Firstly I wrote a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` like this.

```
package com.example.handlers;

public class ObservableReturnValueHandler implements AsyncHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType) {
        return returnValue != null && supportsReturnType(returnType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter returnType) {
        return Observable.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {

        if (returnValue == null) {
            mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
            return;
        }

        final Observable<?> observable = Observable.class.cast(returnValue);
        WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(webRequest)
                .startDeferredResultProcessing(new ObservableAdapter<>(observable), mavContainer);
    }

    public class ObservableAdapter<T> extends DeferredResult<T> {
        public ObservableAdapter(Observable<T> observable) {
            observable.subscribe(this::setResult, this::setErrorResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a config class to add the `ObservableReturnValueHandler` into the interceptor chain so that it can handle responses. The code is given below.

```
package com.example.config;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.*" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
        returnValueHandlers.add(new ObservableReturnValueHandler());
    }
}
```

Now my Resource/Controller class looks like this.

```
package com.example;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/currencyconverter")
public class CurrencyResource {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrencyConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyConverterService currencyConverterService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rates", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
    public Observable<CurrencyRatesDTO> getCurrencyRates(
            @RequestParam("symbol") Set<String> currencyRates) {
        log.debug("Retrieving currency rates.");
        return currencyConverterService.getCurrencyRates(currencyRates);
    }
}
```

The main class which is the entry point to the micro service is given below.

```
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaRxDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JavaRxDemoApplication.class, args);

}
```

The issue is when I send a GET request http://localhost:8080/api/currencyconverter/rates?symbol=USD I am getting the following wired error. There is no any error message or exception trace in the console too.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1485742987017,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/currencyconverter/rates"
}
```

Then I debugged the code and found that the controller method is invoked, REST endpoint is invoked successfully from the controller. A subscription is made to the Observable, result is received and set to the `DeferredResult` successfully inside the `ObservableReturnValueHandler`. What happens afterwards would lead to this error.

You may find the current code at [returnvaluehandler branch of the project](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/SpringBootRxJava/tree/returnvaluehandler). All the necessary steps to start and run the project is given in the readme file shipped with the project. What I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `@RestController` or annotate your method with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks a lot. Actually I am in debt to you for this reply. I posted two questions to get this thing done.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.*" })
```

should be

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
```

The 404 is because your controller is not being picked up by the component scan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that is not the actual issue. The request reaches the controller, invoke the REST end point successfully. Then it receives the response asynchronously and set the deferred results. Everything goes well up to this. Something happens afterwards leads to this error. I updated the answer emphasizing that.